# Using PHP Header to force download

Tags: php

I'm using this code to force a download using headers, the file name is renamed correctly but the file is empty, the actual file isn't being downloaded.

```
$file = url . '/uploads/audio/' . $trackFile;

$tmp = explode(".", $file);
$newTrackName = $trackTitle . '.' . end($tmp);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $newTrackName); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
```

Comment: You are not sending the file to the client, see [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: What is `url` should that be `$url` maybe

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the actual sending of the file e.g.

```
echo readfile($file);
exit;
```

or

```
header("Location: $file");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add..

```
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Its still downloading an empty file, the files url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct and I upvoted both answers but I also found that the new version of cpanel turned of fopen by default, I had to enable fopen.

Comment: You probably mean that _making HTTP requests_ via fopen was disabled? Well then the question would be, why are you using a URL in the first place - are those uploaded files located on a different server? If not, you should use a file system path, not a URL. Making an additional HTTP request to your own system to get data that could as well be read from the file system directly is unnecessary overhead.